Minimizing vertical integral of a Mellin transform
Let $\eta:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ satisfy $\eta(0)=1$ and $\int_0^\infty \eta(x) dx = 1$ (say).
Write $M\eta$ for the Mellin transform of $\eta$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be small.
What is the choice of $\eta$ that makes $$\int_{-\epsilon-i\infty}^{-\epsilon+i\infty} |M\eta(s)| |ds|$$
minimal? What is that minimum?

EDIT: It seems (seems!) clear that the minimum will have to be roughly of the form $c_1 \log(1/\epsilon)+ c_2$, for the following reason. Because $\eta(0)=1$, the Mellin transform $M\eta$ has a pole at $s=0$ with residue $1$; that is, in a neighborhood of $s=0$, it behaves like $1/s$. Now, $$\int_{-\epsilon-i}^{-\epsilon+i} \frac{|ds|}{|s|} = \int_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+1}} = 2 \log\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}} + \frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) > 2 \log \frac{2}{\epsilon}.$$ If you feel that the neighborhood $(-\epsilon-i,\epsilon+i$ is too large, consider that $s$'s not very close to $0$ have to make at least a constant contribution to the integral of $|M\eta(s)|$, by the Mellin inversion theorem.

@StevenClark Without the $i$ factor.

@StevenClark But when have I tried to minimize the second integral you mention? Do you mean $2 \text{lim}_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(\int_0^\infty \left|\eta\left(\sqrt{t^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\right| dt\right)$, that is, $\eta$ instead of $\hat{\eta}$? Even then, I don't quite see the relation.

@StevenClark Ah, I didn't see the absolute value $|s|$ signs around your $s$. They shouldn't be there.

$|ds|$ is not the same thing as $ds$; the problem is that you put absolute-value bars around $s$ in the argument.

If $$\int\limits_{-\epsilon-i\infty}^{-\epsilon+i\infty} |\hat{\eta}(s)|, |ds| \ne \int\limits_{-\epsilon-i\infty}^{-\epsilon+i\infty} |\hat{\eta}(|s|)|, ds$$ please clarify the meaning of $|ds|$.

$|d s|$ is simply the length of the infinitesimal unit $ds$. This is the same as $\int_{-c-i\infty}^{-c+i\infty} |\widehat{\eta}(s)| \frac{ds}{i}$.

A pole at of the Mellin transform of $\eta(x)$ at $s=0$ could imply the Mellin transform only converges for $\Re(s)>0$. For example for $\eta(x)=e^{-x}$ (where $\eta(0)=1$ and $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \eta(x) , dx=1$), the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_x\eta(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} \eta(x), x^{s-1} , dx=\Gamma(s)$$ is only valid for $\Re(s)>0$. So are you interested in the analytic continuation of cases where the Mellin transform only converges for $\Re(s)>0$ (or more generally $\Re(s)>\alpha$ where $\alpha\ge 0$) as well as cases where the Mellin transform converges for $\Re(s)<0$?

Yes, I am assuming the Mellin transform converges in an open domain containing $[-\epsilon,\infty)+i\infty$.
